# Can we override Conga Template formatting by CSS?

Tags: css, richtextarea, conga

I'm trying to format Conga Rich text output field on our page by using CSS, I'm not sure this is possible. But simple ,  tags seems working, but font styling, shading, etc. seems not coming up.

Below is how I tried it.

```
    <label class="slds-form-element__label"><apex:outputField 
value="{!CongaObjField.Text__c}" styleClass="slds-form-element__label"/></label>
```

I could apply font color as per CSS for now, but needs other styling as well.
Any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
<style type="text/css">
    .slds-form-element__label{
                background-color: blue!important; 
                color:red !important;
            }   
    </style>
```